# Adding a retry condition using wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code for posting to an API

```
$post_response = wp_remote_post(
  $url,
  array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "timeout" => 45,
    "headers" =>  $headers, 
    "body" => $jsonData,
    "sslverify" => false
  )
);
```

Here I have added a timeout of 45 seconds, since sometimes the API takes long time to return an output back to the server.

Can anyone tell me an alternative way of adding a retry condition to send a post so that in case the api takes too long to send back an output then I should be able to trace those responses also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
while(1) {
    $post_response = wp_remote_post(
      $url,
      array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "timeout" => 45,
        "headers" =>  $headers, 
        "body" => $jsonData,
        "sslverify" => false
      )
    );
    if (!empty($post_response) && $post_response["response"]["code"] == 200) {
        break;
    }
    echo "Post request failed: " .  $post_response["response"]["message"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the answer above (because it won't let me edit apparently), you should check if the response is a WP_Error also, otherwise you'll get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array`.

```php
while(1) {
    $post_response = wp_remote_post(
      $url,
      array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "timeout" => 45,
        "headers" =>  $headers, 
        "body" => $jsonData,
        "sslverify" => false
      )
    );
    if (!empty($post_response) && ! is_wp_error($response) && $post_response["response"]["code"] == 200) {
        break;
    }
    echo "Post request failed: " .  $post_response["response"]["message"];
}
```